# Window title in screen session not saved

Tags: linux, console, freebsd, gnu-screen

I use `screen` in centos, but the title of window not saved after call to any command.

Stack:

```
# Create a screen
$ screen
# Create a new window in screen
# Ctrl + a: c
# Set title of window
# Ctrl + a: A
# Write a "Some" window title (See screenshot #1)
# Execute command "ls"
$ ls
# After this command the title of window will be reseted (See screenshot #2)
```

How i can save the title of window in screen?

P.S. If i run the demonize process or another process with custom console (Redis or PostgresSQL as example), the window title saved.

Thank.

[image: Screenshot #1]
[image: Screenshot #2]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Naming-Windows

> screen has a shell-specific heuristic that is enabled by setting the
>   window's name to search|name and arranging to have a null title
>   escape-sequence output as a part of your prompt. The search portion
>   specifies an end-of-prompt search string, while the name portion
>   specifies the default shell name for the window. If the name ends in a
>   ‘:’ screen will add what it believes to be the current command running
>   in the window to the end of the specified name (e.g. name:cmd).
>   Otherwise the current command name supersedes the shell name while it
>   is running.
>
> Here's how it works: you must modify your shell prompt to output a
>   null title-escape-sequence ( k  ) as a part of your prompt.
>   The last part of your prompt must be the same as the string you
>   specified for the search portion of the title. Once this is set up,
>   screen will use the title-escape-sequence to clear the previous
>   command name and get ready for the next command. Then, when a newline
>   is received from the shell, a search is made for the end of the
>   prompt. If found, it will grab the first word after the matched string
>   and use it as the command name. If the command name begins with ‘!’,
>   ‘%’, or ‘^’, screen will use the first word on the following line (if
>   found) in preference to the just-found name. This helps csh users get
>   more accurate titles when using job control or history recall
>   commands.